# My decryption is incorrect only for the last character. How do I solve this?

Tags: python

I've been writing a encryption and decryption system based off of squaring ASCII values and adding random numbers to it. The method of encryption is below:

```py
def encrypt(text,x):
    a = x
    key = random.randint(1,10)
    textList = []
    output= ''
    for i in text:
        x += x+key
        textList.append(chr(ord(i)**2+x))
        textList.append(' ')
    for i in textList:
        output += i
    return(output,key)
```

And the method of decryption is below:

```py
def decrypt(text,x,key):
    encryptedList = text.split(' ')
    #print(encryptedList) #This was used for debugging
    output = ''
    for i in encryptedList:
        x -= x+key
        output += (chr(int(math.floor(math.sqrt(ord(i)-x)))))
    return output
```

When I input `hello` and an x-value of `3` into the encrypt function, it returns `⩋ ⟴ ⷋ ⸋ ㄜ` . The result cannot be replicated as it uses random numbers. The encrypt is still normal. However, when I put the result back in the decrypt function,
`decrypt('⩋ ⟴ ⷋ ⸋ ㄜ',3,5)` *(5 is the random number generated)*
it returns with
`hellp` and `p` is one letter in front of `o` in the alphabet and in ASCII.

I've tried using different functions to try and fix the error, including:

- Adding a trailing space
- Using `math.floor()` and `math.ceil()` alongside with `int()`

Comment: You should rather `round` your square root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of issues with your code, but here's a version that has those issues fixed and some comments about the changes:

```
import math
import random


def encrypt(text, x):
    # a = x - a is not used
    key = random.randint(1, 10)
    # textList = [] textList is only used to create output
    output = ''
    for i in text:
        x += x + key
        # may as well add the character and the space once
        output += chr(ord(i) ** 2 + x) + ' '
    return output, key  # no parentheses needed


def decrypt(text, x, key):
    # since you also add a ' ' after the last character, you
    # end up with an empty string at the end of the list, so
    # that has to be left off for the code not to fail
    encryptedList = text.split(' ')[:-1]
    output = ''
    for i in encryptedList:
        # you need the same x for each character, so add again
        x += x + key
        # no parentheses needed on outside of expression
        # no floor was needed, with correct x, 'decryption' works
        output += chr(int(math.sqrt(ord(i) - x)))
    return output


msg = 'hello'
start = 3
text, key = encrypt(msg, start)
print(decrypt(text, start, key))
```

Here's the same code without the comments and avoiding the odd spaces in between the characters, which aren't really needed:

```
import math
import random


def encrypt(text, x):
    key = random.randint(1, 10)
    output = ''
    for i in text:
        x += x + key
        output += chr(ord(i) ** 2 + x)
    return output, key


def decrypt(text, x, key):
    output = ''
    for i in text:
        x += x + key
        output += chr(int(math.sqrt(ord(i) - x)))
    return output


msg = 'hello'
start = 3
text, key = encrypt(msg, start)
print(decrypt(text, start, key))
```

The whole thing could just be reduced to these lines though:

```
import math
import random


def encrypt(text, x):
    key = random.randint(1, 10)
    return ''.join([chr(ord(i) ** 2 + (x := x + key)) for i in text]), key


def decrypt(text, x, key):
    return ''.join([chr(int(math.sqrt(ord(i) - (x := x + key)))) for i in text])


msg = 'hello'
start = 3
text, key = encrypt(msg, start)
print(decrypt(text, start, key))
```

Note that your code works with the changes in the first example given, but that it will only work for texts of limited length, as your `x` will grow and grow and may wrap around at some point, or end up on a value for which there is no code point and `chr()` might fail.

If you want to create a cypher like this, you should probably add to `x` modulo some value, to have it work for larger texts as well.

Also note that this is effectively similar to a Caesar cypher of sorts, so not very hard to crack and shouldn't be used to secure anything important.

A final note, as an example, `decrypt()` could also be written like:

```
''.join([chr(int(math.sqrt(ord(i) - (x + key * n)))) for n, i in enumerate(text)])
```

That avoids keeping track of `x` using the walrus operator, which isn't very easy to read and understand. It does end up a bit longer with the `enumerate()` but I think it makes it clearer how the cypher actually works. The same could be applied to `encrypt()` of course.